# c# shorten path "C:\Users\me\..\you" to "C:\Users\you"

Tags: c#

Is there a built in way of removing unnessacary statements like this `\hello\..` from a path in C# or do I have to do this using regex replace?

Example:

`C:\Users\me\myfolder\..\anotherFolder\image.png` to `C:\Users\me\anotherFolder\image.png`
`C:\Users\me\myfolder\..\..\you\f\image.png` to `C:\Users\you\f\image.png`

my solution using regex would be removing this `/\\([^\.\\]+)\\\.\./` using a loop [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/6340n)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to write this:

```
string fixedPath = Path.GetFullPath(@"C:\Users\me\myfolder\..\anotherFolder\image.png"));
```

Result in `fixedPath`:

> C:\Users\me\anotherFolder\image.png